# Entity Framework SaveChanges Async

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, task, entity-framework-6

I am currently working on an audit trail feature and using the entity framework.

the current code works but takes long time to run.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {

  public int SaveChanges() {
    // get changes from ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()

    // generate custom audit trail records

    return base.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

I was thinking of moving the audit trail building after the save changes and doing it async

```
public int SaveChanges() {
  // get changes from ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()

  int ret = base.SaveChanges();

  // call async function to create audit

  return ret;
}
```

I have tried using async-await but I encountered problems where the object has been disposed. I'm not really used to threading/async calls.

Is there like a way to do a "partial" return where the parent process gets the desired return inorder to continue its process, while the object is still alive/not-disposed to continue the async task.

```
public int SaveChanges() {
  // get changes from ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()

  int ret = base.SaveChanges();

  // partial return ret;

  // continue process in generating audit trail
}
```

Comment: which object was disposed? Can you post the code that caused that to happen?

Comment: hi ned. using the ChangeTracker entries and traversing them to build the audit trail, this threw the error. " var dbValue = dbEntityEntry.GetDatabaseValues()"

Comment: @MiloCabs Just giving the line of code that threw the error without the rest of the code doesn't help much.

Comment: this just means that the context was already disposed when trying to access the dbEntityEntry

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario using Async Await may not work as in cases where your background process outlive the lifetime of parent process you may face situations like the one you are facing.

If you are running framework 4.5.2 or if you can upgrade to that then the best option in your scenario would be to use QueueBackgroundWorkItem API.Below are links for usage

http://codingcanvas.com/using-hostingenvironment-queuebackgroundworkitem-to-run-background-tasks-in-asp-net/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx

If you are on framework 4.5 you can use IRegisteredObject implementation as suggested in this post

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Comment: Im working with 4.5. the blog suggest an implementation of a recurring background job. I was looking for an implementation that would like exit the method call but keeps the object alive since there is still a running async/background job

Comment: That is exactly the purpose...Asyn await is not the right option for you.You can go with IRegisteredObject implementation.I have used both approaches couple of times in similar scenarios.Will see if I can find the code sample to post .

Comment: IRegisteredObject is under System.Web. My dbContext and db models are under another project. Is it still the same implementation?

Comment: Yes...Its under namespace System.Web.Hosting...This is used to register your task with Hosting environment so that host can manage the lifetime of your item even if you program cease to exist